# How to Incorporate Upward Trend into XGBoost Time Series Forecasting

Tags: time-series, linear-regression, xgboost

I'm working with an XGBoost XGBRegressor model right now, attempting to utilize it to predict time-series forecasted data. My dataset is not publicly available, so I will use general terms to describe it:

- It is working to predict at most 2.5 years out, working on 4.5 years of data to predict this.
- The dataset's target values go up and down seasonally, yet has a constant upward trend throughout the entire dataset (think the stock market, or average earth temperatures).
- My XGRegressor model is able to capture these intra-yearly trends (the yearly up's and down's) quite well, however is unable to notice the overall upward trend.

If a line of best fit were to be applied to my current predicted data, it would be horizontal, and I need it to have a positive slope. I've heard rumors of people able to incorporate linear regression trends into their XGBRegressors, or using two models at once, however I can't find anyone that knows this. However, just a simple line-of best fit incorporation would work just fine for now.

Thanks!

Comment: You could indeed try to use a linear regression to first fit the overall trend of time series, and then use an xgboost model to fit on the error of the linear regression to predict the more fine grained changes.

Comment: @Oxbowerce that sounds excellent, how might one do that? Or can you point me in the direction of an article or something that highlights that because I can't seem to find anything.

Comment: You would simply first fit a regression to the data to capture the overall trend in the data, then take the difference between the actual values and what the model predict to get the error. You can then fit another model such as xgboost on this error, and by adding up the two predictions you would get the overall prediction. It might be useful to create a custom class/sklearn estimator for combining these two models.